# CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'dt' before all references to it are out of scope

Tags: c#

When I run code analysis tool I get the following:

> Warning 1 CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'Class1.test.testMethod()', object 'dt' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'dt' before all references to it are out of scope.
>   How to resolve the warnings??

```
public void testMethod()
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   DataTable dt1= new DataTable();
      try
      {
         if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
         {
            dt1.Merge(dt);
         }
      }
      catch
      {
         throw;
      }
      finally
      {
         if (dt != null) dt.Dispose();
         if (dt1 != null) dt1.Dispose();
      }
}
```

Comment: `object 'dt' is not disposed along all exception paths` I think the compiler is actually complaining about the empty catch block, but using a using statement (like the currently top rated answer) should be the best practice as you don't even need to call dispose then. EDIT: +1 for being bothered about warnings.

Answer (score 5):

Not really sure why you are getting that error, but you can try [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement block in your method and see if the error goes away. Try it like:

```
public void testMethod()
{
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    using (DataView dv = new DataView(dt))
    {
        //your work
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I noticed that after I posted - I deleted the comment and the downvote.  Your syntax is definitely preferred over the OP's, but you did miss why the error's happening.

Comment: @DanPuzey, missing tools on my machine, otherwise I would have confirmed, but still ,my guess is that instantiation is done outside the try block.

Comment: @saliqueahmad, you are welcome, did that resolve the warning ?

Answer (score 2):

From [**Dispose objects before losing scope**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> If a disposable object is not explicitly disposed before all
>   references to it are out of scope, the object will be disposed at some
>   indeterminate time when the garbage collector runs the finalizer of
>   the object. Because an exceptional event might occur that will prevent
>   the finalizer of the object from running, the object should be
>   explicitly disposed instead.
>
> To fix a violation of this rule, call `System.IDisposable.Dispose` on
>   the object before all references to it are out of scope.
>
> Note that you can use the using statement (Using in Visual Basic) to
>   wrap objects that implement `IDisposable`. Objects wrapped in this
>   manner will automatically be disposed at the close of the using block.

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
using (DataView dv = new DataView(dt))
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the 7th line in your code you have created a dummy DataTable that is not used. The compiler is complaining about that DataTable and DataView objects. Change the code like below and it will work.

```
public class Class1
{
    public class test
    {
        public void testMethod()
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            DataView dv = null;


         try
        {
            // dt must be assigned a value only within the try block
            dt = new DataTable(dt);
            dv = new DataView(dt);
         }
        catch
        { }
        finally
        {
            if (dt != null) dt.Dispose();
            if (dv != null) dv.Dispose();

         }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

if you dispose both `dt` and `dv` you will get [CA2202 error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx). This is because `dt` is being disposed twice. Once while disposing `dt` and once while disposing `dv`. To avoid that you must assign `null` to `dt` at the end of the try/catch block.

```
    try
    {
        dt = new DataTable(dt);
        dv = new DataView(dt);
        dt=null;
     }
```

Comment: No, you have nulled both objects, and now the code will fail because `dt` is `null`.  You only needed to null `dv`.

Comment: Thanks Manoj by initiallizing it to null.Warnings are removed.

Comment: @salique, you could accept or upvote the answers that helped you

Comment: @DanPuzey `dt` must be assigned null outside the try block. You can't assign any other object. Also, you need not down vote every other answer in order to raise your answer up.

Comment: @ManoRK: I've done no such thing; I've downvoted two answers that had non-working code in them.  You've just *edited* your answer to fix it, and as such I'll remove the downvote - but you *could* assign `dt` outside of the try block.

Comment: @DanPuzey: The code in your answer will still throw the `CA2000` warning. Please validate it.

Comment: @ManojRK: this is really a comment on my answer, not yours.  I have run my code through analysis with VS2012, FxCop's "All rules" set and CA2000 is *not* appearing for that method - I only get CA1306, which is a warning about locales.  Please explain what you're doing to see that warning.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the error is happening because you are creating two `DataView`s, and only one of them will ever be disposed: you initialise `dv` to a new `DataView` and then assign another in the `try` block.  The one from the initial assignment won't be disposed when you hit the `finally`, because you'll have no reference to it.

Modify your declaration `DataView dv = new DataView ()` to just declare the variable, and not initialise it:

```
public void testMethod()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataView dv = null;

    try
    {
        dv = new DataView(dt);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dt != null) dt.Dispose();
        if (dv != null) dv.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: This directly fixes your second error message (about `dv`), and indirectly addresses the first (about `dt`).  The first error is raised because, if the redundant initialisation of `dv` were to throw an exception, `dt` would not be disposed - so removing that initialisation fixes the error.

Comment: The error was about "dt" variable and not about "dv" as pointed by your fix. Anyway, +1 for the try.

Comment: It seems the fix explanation was similar to mine and same penalized by you. Technically you are right but I think you took them too literally.

Comment: There was one error about each.  I'll edit to explain why my code change fixes both.

Comment: I think your solution will fix only the second warning, this because your dt initialization with new DataTable simply isn't in the same block with its Dispose. Imagine that instead of DataTable you would have a custom type and its ctor would break.

Comment: If the constructor breaks, there's nothing to dispose, so there's no code path in which `dt` is created and not disposed.  I have tested the code; both analysis errors are fixed.  I did initially miss that you have to explicitly assign `dv = null` to compile, mind you (now fixed).

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what your example code is demonstrating is unclear.

However, if you are trying to clear a false positive on CA2000 when following the MSDN recommended pattern, then there are some known remedies. I outline two cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202237/ca2000-dispose-objects-before-losing-scope-for-unknown-reason/17241412#17241412) where a simple code change enables **Code Analysis** to recognize the recommended pattern:

1. The temporary must be named as the string "temp" prepended in *camelCase* to the ultimate destination `IDisposable`.
2. The ultimate destination `IDisposable` must be the return value of a function.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the DataTable initializer theoretically might break before dispose. You may try to initialize it initially with null and inside the try block with a new DataTable instance. You have the nullable test in finally after all.

Something like

```
public class Class1
{
    public class test
    {
        public void testMethod()
        {
            DataTable dt = null;

         try
        {
            dt = new DataTable();

         }
        catch
        { }
        finally
        {
            if (dt != null) dt.Dispose();
         }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've removed the declaration of `dv` entirely - your code wouldn't compile!

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. My point was in the comment above, did I wrote something wrong? I removed some parts of the code to make a point with only the dt variable.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile; I'd not consider that a useful answer.

Comment: But if my arguments help the warning removal would you consider it useful? Don't mind, I guess it's easier to remove the "competition"

Answer (score 0):

Occurs because you are initializing dt outside of the try block.

```
public void testMethod()
{
    DataTable dt = null;
    DataView dv = null;
    try
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dv = new DataView(dt);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dt != null) dt.Dispose();
        if (dv != null) dv.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

As stated in other answers you can also use using blocks instead of try...finally.

```
public void testMethod()
{
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        using (DataTable dv = new DataView(dt))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

One question: was it your intention to make the `test` class a nested class of `Class1`?

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class test
    {
        public void testMethod()
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            DataView dv = null;


         try
        {
           dv = new DataView(dt);
         }
        catch
        { }
        finally
        {
            if (dt != null) dt.Dispose();
            if (dv != null) dv.Dispose();

         }
        }
    }
}
```